# ¿Como truncar una fecha con tiempo en postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Ejecuto:

```
SELECT NOW()
```

y me aparece:

```
'2017-08-07 10:53:44.207-06'
```

Y yo quiero que me aparezca

```
'2017-08-07'
```

Comment: puedes simplemente usar `SELECT current_date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opcion es castearla con:

```
SELECT now()::date;
SELECT CAST(now() AS date);
```

O puedes siemplemente hacer un:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
```

que trae la fecha actual sin tiempo.

En la documentacion hay mas funciones:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

La función `now()` retorna un objeto del tipo `timestamp with time zone`. Si se desea obtener solamente la parte de la fecha, es necesario hacer hacer un casting al tipo de dato `date`.

Esto se puedes realizar mediante:

```
SELECT CAST(now() AS date);
```

o con la siguiente sintaxis, que es propia de PostgreSQL (no es SQL estándar)

```
SELECT now()::date;
```

Mas info sobre castings en PostreSQL [aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createcast.html)

Comment: Aunque esto puede solucionar la pregunta original, sería ideal que añadieses algo más de información: ¿por qué la resuelve? ¿Hay alguna documentación donde explique cómo funciona?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, gracias por tu comentario. He mejorado la respuesta en base a las sugerencias mencionadas